# Pin/sticky blog post to top of Wordpress page (not home page)

Tags: wordpress, post, sticky

I am able to sticky my blog posts with the edit page tool but it will only sticky to the home page, which I do not want.

Is there a way to sticky a post to always be on top of a page other than the homepage? Like a blog page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for a plugin or set the post's date way in the future (ex: 2028) so it will be the "newest post".